# Is there a place I can find a PPA for memcached on Ubuntu trusty?

Tags: ubuntu, memcached

Is there a place I can find a PPA for memcached on Ubuntu trusty? Usually the maintainers have a PPA but I cannot locate one. If not, I'm sure it could be built manually but I was curious if anyone else was able to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not "find software for me". We are not a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need any ppa ?
memcached is already is in ubuntu repository.

```
root@next-test:~# apt-cache search memcached | grep "memcached -" | tail -1
puppet-module-saz-memcached - Puppet module for memcached
root@next-test:~# lsb_release -a | grep trusty
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: To get an always up-to-date version :)